# Getting a cross-thread operation exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to update a richtextbox from inside a class, not from the form. Here is my code: I pass the Form as a parameter to the Client class's constructor.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public void AppendText(string s)
     {
         richtextbox_server_activities.AppendText(s + "\n");
     }

     public Form1()
     {
         client = new Client(e.Accepted,e.user,this);
     }

   //rest of the code of the form
 }
```

and the function in the class "Client" where i try to update the gui:

```
private Form1 form;

public Client(string username, Form1 form)
{
    this.form = form;
    _baseSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    this.username = username;
}

private void process()
{
    int id = pr.ReadInt32();
    long index = pr.ReadInt64();
    int size = pr.ReadInt32();
    byte[] buffer = pr.ReadBytes(size);

    TransferQueue queue = _transfers[id];

    queue.Write(buffer, index);

    queue.Progress = (int)((queue.Transferred * 100) / queue.Length);
    if (queue.LastProgress < queue.Progress)
    {
        queue.LastProgress = queue.Progress;

        if (ProgressChanged != null)
        {
             ProgressChanged(this, queue);
        }

        if (queue.Progress == 100)
        {   //HERE IS WHERE I GET EXCEPTION
            this.form.AppendText("Client " + this.username + " has completed uploading the file " + queue.Filename + ".");
            queue.Close();

             if (Complete != null)
             {
                 Complete(this, queue);
             }
         }
}
```

But i am getting an error saying that **Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.** I looked at similar questions, but i still get this error. Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on who (which thread) is calling that `process` method.

Comment: @UweKeim a function in the Client class calss that process function

Comment: Just be sure the main UI thread is updating the controls.

Comment: @panpa It doesn't depend on which method in which class calls that method. It depends on which **thread** calls it as Uwe says..

Comment: @James i could not find a way to update it from the main UI thread, because here is the scenario: This is a client-server applciation, and client send data through sockets, for example when client clicks a button, server's gui prints message saying that client clicked that button. And client and server are in different projects

Comment: @L.B i create a new thread while sending data, and call the function from this thread. So, is that the problem? Am i getting the error since this is a different thread? What can i do about that

Comment: @pana No matter how you justify the reasons; you will not convince the .NET framework to make an exception for you ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim you are right, i just wanted to explain why i did not update gui from main UI thread :)

Comment: @panpa Now search on SO. There are millions of answers for this exception  about  updating UI in a different thread.

Comment: @L.B i found the solution at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are accessing `Form1` controls with another thread in the `Client` class, you need to invoke onto the correct thread.

Example:

```
public void AppendText(string s)
{
    Invoke((Action)delegate { richTextBox1.AppendText(s + "\n"); });
}
```

It may be a better option to pass in a `delegate` into `Client` instead of the entire Form

Example:

```
 public Form1()
 {
     client = new Client(e.Accepted,e.user,AppendText);
 }



public class Client
{
    private Action<string> _callback;

    public Client(string username, Action<string> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }


    private void Process()
    {
        .......

        _callback("Client " + this.username + " has completed uploading the file " + queue.Filename + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i did another way of doing it and it worked. I followed the instructions of this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you use [`IProgress<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it does basically the same thing as the passing the delegate solution but it does the Invoke for you (It invokes on whatever `SynchronizationContext` [`Progress<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was created on).

Comment: I assumed .NET3.5 as its winforms, but yes if .NET4.5 then this is a better option

Comment: `IProgress` is available for 4.0 via the NuGet package [`Microsoft.Bcl`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/)